# Convert IEnumerable<X> to List<Y>

Tags: c#, linq, generics

i have, (in Linq), an IEnumerable of type Client.
Now i have to return a Generic List of type ClientVM.
ClientVM is a subset of Client (not a subtype or anything), and i can't get it to work.

Below is the code i have so far, but it doesn't work this way.
But maybe this code can give you an addition to my post to specify what i want to do:

```
clientVMs = clients.ToList().ConvertAll(new ClientVM( z => z.Reference, z=>z.Fullname ));
```

clientVMs is a generic `List<ClientVM>,` class ClientWM has a constructor that takes the two properties, clients is the `IEnumerable<Client>`

And, offtopic, the compiler messages when you're dealing with Generics aren't readible for humans, imho.

Comment: this is the compiler message: Error 1 The type arguments for method 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Client>.ConvertAll<TOutput>(System.Converter<Client,TOutput>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
var clientVMs = clients.Select(c => new ClientVM(c.Reference, c.Fullname))
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: So fast, and i like the select too! And so 'why didn't i think of it' :)

Answer (score 2):

You've got the wrong syntax for the delegate inside `ConvertAll`:

```
clientVMs = clients.ToList().ConvertAll(z => new ClientVM( z.Reference, z.Fullname ));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
clients.ToList().Select(new ClientVM{ z => z.Reference, z=>z.Fullname }).ToList();
```

Comment: That doesn't actually return a list; it returns an enumerable

Answer (score 1):

Your lambda expressions are misplaced. You probably want:

```
var clientVMs = clients.ToList().ConvertAll(
    client => new ClientVM(client.Reference, client.Fullname));
```